# draw lines from section of an included image in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, tikz-arrows

I have in tikz included this image, and want to draw arrows from each "section". The arrows should be pointing to the right side.. is that possible?..

Is there a native way in which the included image can be divided into section (6 equally divided sections), and draw arrows out from them in tikz?..

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (img) at (0,0)
        {\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{img/specto_snap.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

What I have done now, is created the section with lines in paint, and included the image, is it possible to alter the included in image in tikz? or is this the solution?

Comment: See `overpic`. [overpic – Combine LaTeX commands over included graphics](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/overpic).

Comment: @Bobyandbob Why `overpic`, if the image is already in a TikZ-node? I mean, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Comment: How do you determine the divisions? Is it just 6 equal parts?

Comment: Yes..  6 equal parts.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It was my first idea. You're right. Your proposal is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some help from [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [inner sep=0pt,above right] (img) at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{img/specto_snap}};
\begin{scope}[x=(img.south east),y=(img.north west)]
    % draw dividing lines
    \foreach \y in {1,...,5}
       \draw [red,ultra thick,dashed] (0,\y/6) -- (1,\y/6);

    % draw arrows from middle of each section
    \begin{scope}[-stealth,thick]
        \draw  (0.5,1/12) -- ++(1,0) node[right] {foo};
        \draw  (0.5,3/12) -- ++(1,0) node[right] {bar};
        \draw  (0.5,5/12) -- ++(1,0) node[right] {baz};
        \draw  (0.5,7/12) -- ++(1,0) node[right] {foobar};
        \draw  (0.5,9/12) -- ++(1,0) node[right] {foobaz};
        \draw  (0.5,11/12) -- ++(1,0) node[right] {foobarbaz};
    \end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (Img) {\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=10cm]{example-image}};
  %% Lines
  \foreach \y in {1,...,5}{
    \draw[very thick] ($(Img.south west)!\y/6!(Img.north west)$) -- ($(Img.south east)!\y/6!(Img.north east)$);
  }
  %% Arrows
  \foreach \ylabel [count=\y] in {one,two,three,four,five,six}{
    \draw[very thick,-latex] ($(Img.south)!\y/6-1/12!(Img.north)$) -- +(5,0) node[right]{\ylabel}; 
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]